# How to pause javascript code execution until fetch() actually gets the file

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

Let's say the standard progression on the page kickstarts with the `window load` event like this,

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){   doTheseFirst();   }, { once: true });

function doTheseFirst()
{
  setTimeout(function(){ andThenDoThese(); }, 5000);
  // Maybe show some pictures and play some sounds for 5 seconds
}

function andThenDoThese()
{
  // Show other pictures and play other sounds until user clicks OK
  elementOnPageForOK.addEventListener("click", andThenDoTheseTooWhenUserClicksOK);
}

function andThenDoTheseTooWhenUserClicksOK()
{
  // etc etc
  // You get the idea
}
```

Let's say this piece of code is used over and over again.
But on certain occasions the user has to see a notification before the execution chain gets going. An easy solution for that is using an alert box since it blocks/pauses the code execution. The following code makes the alert box pop up as soon as `fetch()` gets the content from the `txt` file. Note that `fetch()` and `window load` are working independently.

```
fetch("somefolder/notification.txt").then(function(response){return response.text();}).then(function(contentOfTheTxtFile){ alert(contentOfTheTxtFile); });
```

This works because when the alert box is closed, the main code goes back to its normal flow just as needed.

But how do I do the same thing without using a crude alert box that I cannot assign any styles to?
Can I make it so that the code execution is paused as soon as `fetch()` gets the file and then it is unpaused immediately once the user clicks something like an **OK** or **NEXT** button?

Is this possible with async/await?

---

EDIT1: **Further clarification**
Please remember that it is uncertain whether `fetch()` or `window load` will fire the completion signal first. Because download speed is totally unpredictable.
So if we set them both like this, we don't know just how many milliseconds would pass for the other to catch up.

```
if(thisTimeItIsASpecialCase){
 fetch("somefolder/notification.txt").then(function(response){return response.text();}).then(function(contentOfTheTxtFile){ /*What to do when the file is ready*/ });
}
window.addEventListener("load",function(){   doTheseFirst();   }, { once: true });
```

A simplified way to achieve the desired result: Put `doTheseFirst()` function on hold and make it wait for `fetch()` and let it finish its task of getting the file if `fetch()` is indeed trying to get a file. Also let `doTheseFirst()` go ahead and run in case there is no fetching to do.

Comment: I know that we could use setInterval to check every 100ms to see if fetch has the result and ONLY THEN fire doTheseFirst() and finally clearInterval. But that is just not the way it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following

- You define some html where you want to display your content and hide it until your content is really available
- You define a button to hide this element again
- The `next` eventhandler is just there to call a Promise resolve callback which will be defined when needed
- When your text is available to add it to your display and create await a `new Promise` which is resolved upon the click of the next button
- The next handler in the promise chain hide the display again.

This code is of course very rudimentary and schematic. For real use you would encapsulate this in a own class or module. If you are using some framework like React, Angular, ... there are tons of components ready to use, which provide exactly this functionalty. For instance as modal dialog or whatsoever.

```js
var resolver = undefined;

function next() {
  if (resolver) resolver.call();
}

function getText() {
  fetch("https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler&paras=3&format=text")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      document.getElementById("thetext").innerText = text;
      document.getElementById("display").hidden = false;
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolver = resolve;
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      document.getElementById("display").hidden = true;
      resolver = undefined;
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getText()" value="Get Text">

<div id="display" hidden>
  <div id="thetext"></div>
  <input type="button" onclick="next()" value="OK">
</div>
```

Comment: Will this pause all the ticking of setTimeouts and setIntervals until user clicks OK? Because an alert box is able to do just that.

Comment: No, this won't pause any timeouts. The only thing that will do is, it will hide the textarea only after the promise is fulfilled by clicking the button.

Comment: If you have a race condition between `fetch` and `window.load` you have a design problem in your app. If you have tasks that are started independently of each other, they should not rely on each others results. If one of the tasks needs the others results it must only be started once the other task is finished. But from your description of your problem, nobody can see, what you really need ...

Comment: We wouldn't have to call it a design problem if there was another way to control the way things run. If nothing can do what the alert box can do then of course I will have to change the structure of the code.

Comment: @TheLinguist You can perfectly control the way things run if you do it correctly according to the specification of the language you are using. BTW using an `alert` to wait for some other JS function to finish won't work. Because JS is single threaded. Thus, while the alert is shown, not a single other statement is executed.

Comment: I appreciate your time investment and I presume that the good code you have offered will certainly be useful when those in need reach it.

Answer (score -2):

You can show the content of the text file, which you received by `fetch`, in a nice `<div>` or in any element in the fetch and you exit the function.
You add an `EventListener` to a button upon which when user clicks you can move to next action.

Comment: That is obvious but it is not an answer to what was asked.